# Unity / Blender - Do I import the sculpted version of a model or a regular model with a normal map?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I am trying to import a model from blender into unity. I baked a normal map of my sculpted object successfully however have a question.

When I created the normal map I did a technique I learned on youtube where you create a copy of your object before you begin sculpting and then stack both the sculpted and non sculpted objects on top of each other, select both, and then press bake.

**My question is, after creating a normal map of my sculpted object, do I import the non sculpted object with a normal map attached to it or do I import the sculpted version of my object with a normal map attached to it?** I tried to import the non sculpted with a normal map and did see some detail however there was some buggy areas, however, my sculpted version was fine. Is importing sculpted versions of objects to intense on players computers? Thanks.

Comment: depends .. using normal maps doesn't solve everything but often is a good "trick" to keep models low poly but still interesting. It depends how high/low poly you sculpted model is and what your target platform will be ...

Comment: It only had about 200 faces when I looked at it with the decimate modifier. It's a pretty basic model of a barrel and I used dypntopo to sculpt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the low poly with baked normal map - that is the whole point of baking - you can avoid importing a full blown high poly model

Answer (score 0):

In most youtube channels, developers recommend that import separately, because in unity you must check (tell to unity) that your image of normal map, is a normal map and not some random image, you do this after importing. Check this image

[image]